# Change existing layout in Android programmatically

Tags: android, layout

I have used fragment with Tab in Actionbar in android. Bellow is where i set layout for fragment on onCreateView:

```
mFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.second_activity, container, false); 
return mFragmentView;
```

My question is: can I change existing layout(R.layout.second_activity) with another(R.layout.sample_layout) programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
           .detach(this)
           .attach(this)
           .commit();
```

This will force the fragment to call onCreateView again.  Here you can return R.layout.sampleLayout instead of your usual layout.  Set a variable in your fragment before calling the fragment transaction to chose the right layout when this function is called.

A second solution, is to wrap your initial layout in a viewGroup, then call getView.removeAllViews(), inflate your new layout, and add it to the root view.